# Can i dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on different drives?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot, dualboot

I have an SSD that i have Windows 10 installed on and i have a second drive (HDD) and i would want to know if it`s possible to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu and if it is how to step by step because im a beginner.

I would want to keep Windows 10 on SSD and i would want to install Ubuntu on my HDD drive. I know how to shrink a drive, boot from an USB stick

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - boot an installation USB for Ubuntu and direct it to install to the second hard drive.

Dual boot selection will depend on whether you have a UEFI (modern) boot system. If you do then you will have to boot into the UEFI boot manager to select which OS you want to run. For legacy systems it will be more complicated - you may be able to select which disk to boot from the BIOS boot menu or you can shrink the Windows partition and install a grub boot partition to that disk.